# MSSQL Group By failing, but no dup Column names

Tags: sql-server

I know this question has been asked time and time again, but I have no two column names that are the same, yet I am getting:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Column 'dbo.PRODUCT.ProductName'
>   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My ProductId column is unique to my dbo.Product Table, and I am not sure why it is getting confused with another value. In this image you can see the dup ProductIds

[image]

```
WITH products AS
(
    SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p.[ProductName]) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM dbo.PRODUCT p
    JOIN dbo.Category c ON p.ProductCategoryCode = c.CategoryCode
    JOIN dbo.Supplier s ON p.ProductSupplierCode = s.SupplierCode
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTag pt ON pt.ProductUPC = p.UPC
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Tag t ON pt.ProductTagTagCode = t.TagCode
    GROUP BY p.ProductId
) 
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 2;
```

Comment: Why do you need a `GROUP BY` if you're grouping by the `Id` column?

Comment: I am getting Dup items in my output

Comment: My guess is you're not actually getting dup items, but there are multiple matches in one or more of your `JOIN`ed tables.

Comment: I Could, but Distinct is Inefficient from what I hear, and Group By, Order By should be used instead

Comment: Sample results and desired output will help.

Comment: `group by` and `distinct` are equally 'inefficient' as they both require internal ordering. I guess each product has multiple tags, so you need to decide which product tag you want to see.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that is not exactly true.  `GROUP BY` will generally use a hash match and will "not order the result set" (per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)).  `DISTINCT` will sort the elements and remove adjacent duplicates, which in theory is slower but will require less memory than `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Certainly - nothing orders the resultset except an order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you are selecting ALL of the fields in ALL of the tables, but you are only grouping by one value. If a value is returned by the query, then it must either be GROUPED or aggregated (Min, Max, SUM, AVG, etcetera).

If you simply add the Product Name to your grouping:

```
GROUP BY p.ProductId, p.ProductName
```

You will still have the same problem with (for example) p.ProductCategoryCode, p.ProductSupplierCode, c.CategoryCode, etc, etc.

In this case, where you are looking for unique rows, do **not** use `GROUP BY` - use `DISTINCT` (which works on all fields returned automatically) instead. Note that @bjones is still correct as to why you are getting duplicates - one of the tables you are joining in can have multiple rows for each product (e.g. many times a product will come from more than one supplier.)

To solve this, you need to:

- Determine what data you need to return, and only select those columns
- Determine if you need to summarize any data (i.e. Total Sold or On Hand), then:

  - Use `GROUP BY` if you do need to summarize any values, or
  - Use `DISTINCT` if you do not need to summarize any values